# When should I ditch a pot with teflon?

Tags: equipment, kitchen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know whether the teflon coated pan's life has reached end?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18989/how-to-know-whether-the-teflon-coated-pans-life-has-reached-end)

We have this set of teflon covered pots, how do I know when the teflon gets too worn out? Or does it ever?
Things we put in, does not come as easily of, as it did when the were new.

They are aprox. 6 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ehow has an article on the specific dangers non-stick coatings can cause to humans and pets including fumes from heating a pan to too high a temperature,  which I was unaware of.

Of course, if the coating is flaking or fuzzy-looking, actual coating material, which is a carcinogen, can leach into the food cooked in the pan.

Link to the Ehow article:
http://www.ehow.com/list_6531918_dangers-using-teflon-cookware.html

Comment: Eh ow articles are usually either copied from other sites, or of low quality. They exist for google add ranking only! Not workth quoting

Comment: @TFD - do you have any basis for thinking that this particular article has erroneous information?  Do you have any useful info for the OP? Thanks!

Comment: PTFE is not that bad! It's duplicate question anyway, likely to be closed soon. No point in promoting eh ow in the excellent and fully democratic SA site :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of them, and not replace them (with teflon). Teflon is okay for pans, but for pots, it's always good to have a set with really thick, heavy, copper bottoms. Spend the money on a good set and you won't be disappointed.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? Right now, it doesn't answer the question (how to know when the teflon has worn out). It would also be great if you could provide some concrete reasoning or evidence of teflon not being okay on pots, and why pots with copper bottoms are better.